# GWT URL Parameters

Tags: java, url, gwt

What is the proper way to use URL parameters?

My URL is this: http://localhost:8080/#pg5?testing=abc

In my code I try to get the value of testing using this line of code:

```
String value = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getParameter("testing");
```

Unfortunately all this does is set my string to "undefined".

I thought perhaps it wasn't getting the correct URL but this code returns the proper URL:

```
String value = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getHref();
```

I know I can parse the url to get my parameters, but I thought that's what getParamerter() was for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

url should be http://localhost:8080/?testing=abc#pg5 instead of http://localhost:8080/#pg5?testing=abc

Comment: So close - I'm doing something similar - trying to parse the hash as a parameter list/map. Any hints?

Comment: Kieveli, I just wrote the code for that here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16721991/491553 (Yes, I know I'm 2 years too late).