# Create URL Parameters in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, url-parameters

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128575/gwt-url-parameters)

How do I programatically write parameters into the URL using GWT?  I've learned from my previous question that parameters need to go before the anchor, but how do I do that from GWT?

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
Hyperlink pg1 = new Hyperlink("Test", "?testing=abc#pg1");
```

It results in the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Athena.html#?testing=abc%23pg1
```

I was thinking about using Window.Location.assign(), but the javadoc says that will loose the state of my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object HyperLink seems to be for linking to internal states, and probably was written so that changing its href is difficult?

I suggest you use this class http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineHTML.html instead - obviously you are generating the href programatically, so it should be easy to generate the  element to supply to the InlineHTML object.

Comment: That works, I just wish there was some easy built in way to set the parameters, just like there is for getting them.

Comment: I've given up trying to pass parameters using standard url parameters.  GWT works much better when you just give in to their ways ;)

I'm using the following in my application now: http://website.com/page.html#view~testing:abc,foo:bar

I then have a function that reads everything after the hash tag, and puts the parameters in a Map for easy use within my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [this constructor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html#Hyperlink(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which receives a history token as the second constructor argument, hence you are getting said result.

Use the [`setHTML()` method](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html#setHTML(java.lang.String)) to set the correct value on the link.

Comment: Can you provide any examples? I tried setHTML("<a href='?testing=abc'> test </a>") without any luck.