# GWT Method GET, retrieve parameter

Tags: url, gwt, get

I have a gwt url like this

http://127.0.0.1:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#ForumMessage=918

when I am doing this

Window.Location.getParameter("ForumMessage")

I am getting null??

By the way, I not getting the point why this **?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997** in the url!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value of the URL fragment (the part after the `#`) call [`Window.Location.getHash()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#getHash%28%29). This will return all of "ForumMessage=918".

`getParameter()` returns query parameters, not the URL fragment.

[See here for more information about the parts of a URL](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_the_parts_of_a_URL).

The `?gwt.codesvr=` part is needed to run in [Development Mode](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideDevMode).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this topic [GWT URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128575/gwt-url-parameters)

Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128575/gwt-url-parameters/1128681#1128681)

> url should be http://localhost:8080/?testing=abc#pg5 instead of http://localhost:8080/#pg5?testing=abc

and delete that part (?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 ) and run it in web mode. I think it will solve your problem

Comment: I am  currenly developing the application, how to run it in web mode, because in the url when i am deleting this in the url (?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997), an alert containing is being shown GWT module 'biddingsystem' may need to be (re)compiled even when i compile again

Comment: in the run argument and debug argument, i am also trying to remove -codeServerPort 9997 with no success, the source of all my problems is this part ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997. I am using eclipse with the buit in jetty