# working with Query String in GWT

Tags: gwt, query-string

I have to created a dynamic URLcontaining the user id and email parameters, which will direct to sign up form in my GWT application. I want to set and get the parameters in the query string. I have referred tp http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/System/src/com/gawkat/gwt/system/client/global/QueryString.java?r=1241 but here QueryStringData is inaccessible to my project.Please tell me how I can do it? Any alternative could also help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there's a simple tokenized query string parser in GWT. But you can get the raw query string by using:

```
String queryString = Window.Location.getQueryString();
```

Parse it any way you like. I use it like this to set debug flags etc.:

```
boolean debugMode = Window.Location.getQueryString().indexOf("debug=true") >= 0;
```

Note that changing values in the query part of the url (between the `?` and the `#`) will reload the page. While changing the "hash part" of the url (anything after the `#`) will not reload the page. Which is why the com.google.gwt.user.client.History uses the hash part.

Comment: Thanks Stein,can you tell me how can I set parameters in query string like http://localhost:8084/Demo/?id=1 here I want to set and retrieve the id.

Comment: If you want to set and get url parameters using gwt, I reccoment using the hash part. Check out http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html that uses the hash part of the url.

Comment: Thanks Stein for your help now I am able to set value in URL.

Comment: The "hash part" or in GWT parlance "history token" is actually a Fragment Identifier: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Hi Amandeep, 
 Just out of curiosity, you will read the id in the server? If so, how will you make that call(by invoking a method or just by typing in browser). 

Anyhow, the actual question I want to ask is, once you read the "id" in the server, how can you send the data back to the client? will it be just plain html or a page that would have GWT elements?

Answer (score 14):

@Stein, but there is (a query parameter tokenizer in GWT): e.g. [`Window.Location.getParameter("debug")`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) will return the string value of the parameter `debug`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want really want to parse the history token (hash part) to encode parameters, here's the code for that:

```
private static Map<String, String> buildHashParameterMap() {
    final String historyToken = History.getToken();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (historyToken != null && historyToken.length() > 1) {
        for (String kvPair : historyToken.split("&")) {
            String[] kv = kvPair.split("=", 2);
            if (kv.length > 1) {
                paramMap.put(kv[0], URL.decodeQueryString(kv[1]));
            } else {
                paramMap.put(kv[0], "");
            }
        }
    }

    return paramMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is in-built support for getting all of the parameters.

Simply call:

```
     Map<String, List<String>> parameterMap = Window.Location.getParameterMap();
```