# Passing query String for GWT application

Tags: gwt

I am developing a GWT application. I have an option in existing feature like when specific URL pattern is given, it goes to server and comes back to client.
Example:
 www.example.com/abc/def?value=xy. this goes to servlet, reads value xy, adds a cookie for that value, comes to client, reads cookie to get value xy.

Is there any possibility to get value passed in URL directly in client side?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

Comment: that page shows how to make calls to server, my question is how to get value from query string in client side

Comment: Is it this you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261529/working-with-query-string-in-gwt

Comment: exactly.. thank you so much.. and sorry to post a duplicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a single parameter

```
Window.Location.getParameter("value");
```

Or to get all parameters in a Map:

```
Window.Location.getParameterMap()
```